# how to use Google Cloud API - Application Default Credentials for text detection

Tags: java, google-authentication, google-cloud-vision

i have used following java code to detect a text of a image, but here problem is i couldn't able to authenticate correctly

```
 public static void detectText() throws Exception, IOException {

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();

    List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();

    ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.readFrom(new FileInputStream("/home/buddika/Desktop/car_number_pate_16.jpeg"));

    Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
    Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.TEXT_DETECTION).build();
    AnnotateImageRequest request =
            AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
    requests.add(request);

    try (ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = client.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
        List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

        for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
            if (res.hasError()) {
                System.out.println("Error: %s\n"+ res.getError().getMessage());
                return;
            }

            // For full list of available annotations, see http://g.co/cloud/vision/docs
            for (EntityAnnotation annotation : res.getTextAnnotationsList()) {
                System.out.println("Text: %s\n" + annotation.getDescription());
                System.out.println("Position : %s\n" + annotation.getBoundingPoly());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i am having below error message once execute this code lines

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:98)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
    at com.security.management.system.api.google_cloud_api.TextDetect.detectText(TextDetect.java:157)
    at com.security.management.system.api.google_cloud_api.TextDetect.main(TextDetect.java:48)
```

following libs were used

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.cloud.vision.spi.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.*;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature.Type;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

note i have used the .json file also which downloaded accring to the instruction given from this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#callingjava)

note :- i have set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable in .bashrc file

could you please help me on this issue

Comment: Did you read the entire message? `The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.`  Are you running on GAE? If not, did you set the environment variable to point to the credentials?

Comment: Indeed, you say you've "used the .json file" - please give details about *how* you've used it.

Comment: i have put the .json file in resource directory and tried this code line to get the default settings   GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(); @JonSkeet

Comment: @JimGarrison  GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(); this is the way i have tried it

Comment: @BuddhikaAlwis: Just putting the JSON file in the resource directory isn't going to do anything. It needs to be a file on the file system at execution time, and then you need to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to specify the location. Additionally, you're not *using* the credential when you create the client... If the default application credentials are working, you shouldn't need to load them manually at all, but if you *do* load them manually, you should specify them in `ImageAnnotatorSettings`.

Comment: @JonSkeet could you please help on this , yes there a code change need to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable. if it is yes please tell me the way. i have entered a envirement variable entry in the .bashrc also , but it wouldnt work. what i am missing here

Comment: @JonSkeet could you please have a code example for that to set that settings manually - ImageAnnotatorSettings, it is better if you can add that code line in my code lines

Comment: No, you don't need code to set the environment variable. You just set it in the environment. Is there a reason you can't do that? But no, you don't need the settings explicitly if you're using the default credentials. But you don't need you credentials variable either.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth i have followed this link and set the export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/buddika/IdeaProjects/bitbucket/security-management-system/modules/security-management-system-api/src/main/resources/SecurityManagementSystem-e7427cb89a80.json env valrible as this way , but still i am getting the same erorr @JonSkeet

Comment: @BuddhikaAlwis: Then it sounds like you haven't exported it in the right way. Please edit the post (don't just add a comment) explaining how you've set the variable and how you're running the code. (If you just export it in one shell and then run the code in another shell, that won't help.) You could log the value of the environment variable from inside your code to check...

Comment: I am facing same issue on ubuntu 16.0 server, I have set Env variable according to documentation but client library is still throwing error

Answer (score 0):

I used google cloud vision api with spring boot. And able to extract text from images.

for credentials added below properties.

*application.properties* file:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=mycloud-123456
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/service-account.json.
```

added dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Your above function is working in the project. commented line which were defining GoogleCredential.

```
@RequestMapping("/gettext")
 public String detectText() throws Exception, IOException {

        //GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
    String finalText = "Ta Da! No value";
        List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();

        ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.readFrom(new FileInputStream("G:\\files\\type1.jpeg"));

        Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
        Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.TEXT_DETECTION).build();
        AnnotateImageRequest request =
                AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder()
                        .addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
        requests.add(request);

        try (ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {
            BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = client.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
            List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

            for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
                if (res.hasError()) {
                    System.out.println("Error: %s\n"+ res.getError().getMessage());
                    return "";
                }

                // For full list of available annotations, see http://g.co/cloud/vision/docs
                for (EntityAnnotation annotation : res.getTextAnnotationsList()) {
                    finalText += annotation.getDescription();
                    System.out.println("Text: %s\n" + annotation.getDescription());
                    System.out.println("Position : %s\n" + annotation.getBoundingPoly());
                }
            }
        }
        return finalText;
    }
```

Note: Created service account and downloaded json, steps [Create a service account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en)

Note: I haven't used the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable. so deleted library *com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential*.